# "Protect" .docx properties from editing

Tags: c#, openxml, docx

It's possible to "protect" `.docx` **content** with password from edititng. [Example](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsod/2010/04/05/how-to-set-the-editing-restrictions-in-word-using-open-xml-sdk-2-0/)

But is it possible to "protect" **some or all file properties**, for example, Author, Title, Server(custom) properties?

If not, what's the best way (convert docx to pdf?) to protect user from accidental editing while maintaining viewing of document?

Comment: Maybe by using Microsoft Rights Management?  DRMEncryptProperty: Specify whether to encrypt all metadata stored inside a rights-managed file.  See further https://www.stigviewer.com/stig/microsoft_office_system_2010/2015-06-23/finding/V-17769

Comment: I'm considering this option too. Thx for highlighting this feature. Will discuss this with the customer, to make sure all requirements met: 1. Client Office editions https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd772650(v=ws.10).aspx 2.  docs are opened within AD machines. Btw, is that all requirements?